# Python sum of a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, sum

I'm new to programming and I found something what can help in my current job. Program is reading external text files and getting a specific value of time from every file in folder. I've got to the point where I have the output I need but I can't to sum it. It seems like my code returns number for every file separately.

my code:

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.lst'), recursive=True):
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') as f:
        for lines in f:
            if "'INTERNAL_DATA',103,1,'','T','','" in lines:                                                                                         
                workTime = lines.split("'INTERNAL_DATA',103,1,'','T','','")[-1].strip()                                                                              
                workSec = int(workTime[9:11])

                print(workSec)

my result: 
23 
55 
16 
53 
56
```

...and what I need is the sum of these results. I've tried to sum it with a for loop but it gives the same output. Can someone help me?

Comment: Post the [MCVE] of what you tried that didn't work; it's usually more helpful for the future if we can say what you did wrong *and* how to fix it, not merely writing the correct code for you.

Comment: ok, so the problem was that "workSec" should be declared right above all this code. Lesson for me

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the value to your `workSec` variable in each loop. You will also need to initialize it to 0 outside the loop so you can use it in the arithmetic expression.

```py
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.lst'), recursive=True):
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') as f:
        workSec = 0
        for lines in f:
            if "'INTERNAL_DATA',103,1,'','T','','" in lines:                                                                                         
                workTime = lines.split("'INTERNAL_DATA',103,1,'','T','','")[-1].strip()                                                                              
                workSec = workSec + int(workTime[9:11])

                print(workSec)
```

Comment: I tried to implement it in few ways but it's still:
23 
55 
16 
53 
56